# Как назвать функцию словом input?

Tags: python

В яп Python много слов, которые 'зарезервированы': def, return, input и пр. Как сделать чтобы интерпретатор воспринимал

```
def input():
    print('Life, sky and Universe')

input()
```

как вызов функции?

Или например

```
def return()
    print('')
return()
```

?

Comment: input не зарезервированное слово, вы можете назвать так функцию. Как return - никак, только изменив код интерпретатора и перекомпилировав его.

Comment: @insolor спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input` - это хоть и стандартная, но всё-равно **функция** (то есть **объект** языка питон), вы её можете "перекрыть", ваш первый пример прекрасно работает. Правда, после этого вам становится недоступна стандартная функция `input`.

`return` же - **зарезервированное слово**, питон не может его воспринимать как имя функции, он воспринимает конструкцию `def return` как использование двух ключевых слов подряд и выдаёт ошибку, с этим нельзя ничего сделать.